# Sync files between centOS (ec2) & a NAS

Tags: linux, centos, files, file-sharing, upload

I have made a cronjob, that takes backup locally - of some diffrent files. But i would like to have them copied to a remote server aswell.
The problem is the "remote" server is a NAS server, and im not quite sure how i should go about this.

Inforormation:
* Main server - centOS v7.x
* Backup Server - NAS

Can i do it with just a FTP? or is their some other way i can get access to the NAS server, and remote upload the files?

Comment: ftp is an option but backging up via ftp might be slow. see if you can mount the NAS via samba (smbfs).

Comment: I can somewhat live with it being a little slow, the files are not that big - we are talking a total of 500-700mb. And both servers being on a pretty good connection.    
I just want it to sync and delete files older than a specific date

Comment: Does your NAS allow to connect to it via a SSH connection? You could use rsync to sync your files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i got it to work with lftp, not the optimal solution - but should work fine for smaller files :)

```
HOST=''
USER=''
PASS=''
TARGETFOLDER='/xxx/xxx'
SOURCEFOLDER='/xxx/xxx'

function sync_files_to_remove()
{
lftp -f "
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ssl:verify-certificate no
set ftp:ssl-allow off
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $SOURCEFOLDER
mirror --reverse --delete --verbose $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
bye
"
}
```